# Поиск thepiratebay не поддается парсингу

Tags: php, синтаксический-анализ

Здравствуйте.

Вот никак поиск пайратбея не поддается парсингу, остальные страницы - парсятся.

```
<?
    require 'phpQuery-onefile.php';
    $page_content = file_get_contents('http://thepiratebay.sx/search/Adobe/0/99/0');
    $html = phpQuery::newDocument($page_content);
    foreach($html->find('body') as $value) {
        echo pq($value)->html();
    }
?>
```

Подскажите, что с ним такое, и как возможно его запарсить?

Comment: https://github.com/thekarangoel/TPB

Comment: @eicto, в Питоне, к сожалению, я полный ноль, и вряд ли что-то пойму...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Судя по всему идет проверка на наличие `USERAGENT`.

Так что нужно использовать `cURL`. Попробуйте такую функцию - у меня загружает:

```
function curl_file_get_contents( $url )
{
    if ('' == $url) {
        return '';
    }
    $curl = curl_init(); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; ru; rv:1.9.1.3) Gecko/20090824 Firefox/3.5.3'); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
    return curl_exec($curl);
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, тоже только что разобрался с данной проблемой :)